# Using Java Asserts in Production (but are skipped in prod using a boolean)

Tags: java, exception, boolean, assert, production-environment

I currently have a project in java, and I want to reference methods deployed in production projects in my testing code. I want to avoid having to have 2 versions of the method, one for testing and one for prod, and want to have a boolean flag to "enable/disable" these sections during prod, and then enable them during testing by setting this value to true.

I understand that Asserts throw Errors, and NOT Exceptions, but the code will be skipped during production, so this shouldn't matter. Is this correct?

Is this advised / possible, without any ramifications and assuming that the asserts DO get skipped when running in production?

If not, is there a better way to have access to these methods, without copying them, and to set them into a "testing" state to expose more logging functionality? The exposing of this is not a security concern, and should not have any impact on performance in production.

EDIT: Yes, we do use exceptions correctly in production, and adding these asserts is NOT replacing that. I just want to add asserts for ease of use and avoiding code duplication for testing purposes.

Comment: What asserts are you talking about, JUnit(-like) asserts, or the Java keyword `assert`? Java language asserts are not executed when running with `-da` (disable assertions, the default).

Comment: If you have two versions of the method, how come one is for real-life use (production) and the other one is for anything-else? Looks like there's something missing here, huh?

Comment: I believe they are Junit3 asserts. How would I determine which one they are? The assert statements are: assertNotNull(Object o) as an example.

Comment: We have 2 versions (the copied version is not available in prod) because, currently, we copied the one in production to add asserts. I wanted to know if we can avoid having a copy and add asserts to the one in prod.

Comment: It is my opinion (and what I have seen in practice) that your test code should not be mixed with your production code.  Nor your code should have different execution paths for test and prod environments.  Of course, this is very a generic rule and your case *may* need to do what you ask but have a very good analysis at what you are doing before you embark on this non-standard way of testing your code.

Comment: How else do you make tests involving code in production, where methods in production are very large, and you want to avoid duplication?

Comment: And will there be any issues in normal java execution/compilation involving having asserts in prod code (but are skipped over by boolean tests)?

Comment: If your production code doesn't call your test methods, then why do you need to worry about the asserts? They will never be called. And if it does, then that is your problem.

Comment: Well the issue is I want to have the asserts in the production method, just skipped over by booleans. My ONLY concern is if this will cause oddities during compile time, such as code being skipped (I know i wont have any modifications of objects INSIDE assert lines, so if they get removed during compile, that shouldn't matter.) I just want to make sure that if i have code like this: if(debugTesting){assertNotNull(Object o);} that it wont try to compile the if without a then statement and fail. Thanks!